# Derivative of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

What is the derivative of $$\cos^2 a (\tan a - \tan b)$$ 
Please anyone explain in detail.
The differentiation is with respect to $a$. I tried to obtain the answer using chain rule, but didn't get it. Must be facing some problem. The simplified form is $$1-\sin a \cos a (\tan a-\tan b)$$

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: I am a class 11 student so I hope the solution match my standards

Comment: But how in this case I can use f as a function of g (x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use both the chain rule and the product rules for derivation.

First you have $$\cos^2(a)(\tan(a)-\tan(b))$$

you can first expand to obtain 
$$\cos^2(a)\tan(a)-\cos^2(a)\tan(b)$$

Now the chain rule you have to use it with $\cos^2(a)$, you have $f(a)=\cos(a)$, $g(a)=a^2$ and you have the composite function $g\circ f (a)$.

EDIT: Given $g\circ f (a)$, you want to calculate $\frac{d(g\circ f (a))}{da}$.

So the chain rule says $\frac{d(g\circ f (a))}{da}=\frac{d(f (a))}{da}\cdot \frac{dg(f(a))}{da}$

Now $\frac{d(f (a))}{da}=-sin(a)$, $\frac{dg (f(a))}{da}=2cos(a)$ and therefore $\frac{d(g\circ f (a))}{da}=-2sin(a)cos(a)$

However you will have to use also the product rule, since you have $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$ Of course in the first term, $u=\cos^2(a)$, $v=\tan(a)$.

Therefore, first calculate $u'$, using the chain rule, then calculate $v'$ and then use the product rule formula!

Comment: Yes, I understood that but can u explain the chain rule part please?

Comment: edited over there

Comment: Yes now I get it..but does the derivative square of anything applies the general formula of na^ (n-1)? So in that case cos^2 a changes to 2 cos a, by the general formula...is it plausible?